# take an array from a circular array

Tags: c++, arrays, queue, buffer

So, my goal is to capture data in a buffer.
I need speed and I just need a fixed size so I was thinking that a circular array would be the best.

But what I want to do is at each step to:

- first, overwrite the latest information in the array with the newest that just arrived
- next, using the all array starting from the oldest to the newest
- repeat

I have difficulty to see how to handle the second step in C++ while being efficient. Or maybe something else than a circular array would be better? Any advise or point of view is welcome.

To have something more graphic:

```
for step in steps:
    (current writing position = 2)
    current buffer = [8, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

    new info = 10

    overwrite buffer(new info)
    new buffer = [8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7] 

    current writing position += 1   //(3)

    array to use = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    function(array to use)
```

(I used integer following each other to see the chronology of each information in the buffer)

What I am thinking about is to copy the last part and first part and then concatenate them:

```
std::vector<int>   buffer{8, 9, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7};

std::vector<int>   oldest(&buffer[3],&buffer[6]);
std::vector<int>   youngest(&buffer[0],&buffer[2]);

oldest.insert( oldest.end(), youngest.begin(), youngest.end() );

function(oldest)
```

If you know something that would be quicker please tell me.

Comment: If someone think that to understand my problem it is better to change the pseudo code with c++ let me know. I will change it. 
My current code is  more complex than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need speed you should not copy elements but use the index information you already have to access the elements in the right order.

So the handling function would just need a pointer to the array (or reference to std::vector), know the size and the current working pos.

```
// process from working pos to end of buffer
for(int i  = current_pos; i < buffer_size; ++i) {
   processElement(new_buffer [i]);
}
// process the remainder from begin to working pos
for(int i  = 0; i < curent_pos; ++i) {
   processElement(new_buffer [i]);
}
```

This should not be to hard to inplement as your working position marks both, the begin and end of your data to process.

Comment: the thing is that I am using a third party library and its function need the all array.
I cannot just process one element of the buffer.

Comment: Which type of array does the function take ? Where does it get the size information from ? Meaning how does the function know how many elements to process ?

Comment: Is memory usage an issue ? If not, there is an easy way to reduce the costs of copying extremely.

Comment: it takes a tensorflow::tensor as entry. I was thinking first putting the data in vector (buffer) then creating the tensor with it. But now I am thinking that I can fill the tensor element by element as you wrote. But I feel like it is not that efficient. Concerning the memory no real problem. The speed is the main focus.

Comment: do you have any documentation (link) for the tensor class. maybe there is a fast was to assign multiple values without copying.

Comment: Here is a link. Unfortunatly the documentation for the c++ api is not so clear I think (at least for myself but I am far from being an expert) https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/cc/ClassTensor.html

Answer (score 0):

This approach reduces the copy overhead n-fold where n is the number of extra array elements + 1 used.

Example: array with 2 extra elements

Note, in this case, the oldest value is on the left, the function has been called with pointer to arr[0] (start_pos = 0)

```
arr == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, x, x]
```

now, lets insert the new value 10

```
arr == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, x]

start_pos += 1
```

call function with pointer to the second element (the old 3 won't be used)

```
function(arr + start_pos)
```

and now add the 11 and increment the working position (the old 4 won't be used)

```
arr == [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

start_pos += 1

function(arr + start_pos)
```

Now, the array is full.

And only now it is needed to copy the last elements to the begin of the array (after the start_pos to the end) and set working_pos back to 0
depending on the number of extra elements this needs to be done only every 10th, 100th or even 1000th iteration !

result of copying would be:

```
arr == [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 9, 10, 11]
                            *
start_pos = -1 // prepare for the +1 in regular iteration.
```

next added value (12) will overwrite the * value

```
arr == [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 10, 11]

start_pos += 1 // is 0 now

function(arr + start_pos)
```

Of course, you need one variable to determine the pos to insert the new element behind the other val or you derive from start_pos + nElemsToProcess

If your function() does only take std containers it is probably not the right choice to met the need for speed.

Comment: Thanks! It's really interesting to see other point of view :)
But with this approach we still have to copy at some point right?
Do you have an idea of when it is worth compared to circular buffer where there's no need to copy?
Btw this is what you called extrem copy? (never heard of that before)

Comment: I meant the cost is extremely reduced compared to copying everything into a new array because you can directly access all the elements in a row **without the need to wrap around** as you would need with a circular). The problem is, how Tensor takes the data (always copying !?).

Comment: It seems so :/
I did not find a way to do it differently so far. I will try first you first approach I will copy element per element in the tensor.

Comment: Do you just fill in a series of numbers ? The tensor code is on git hub the TensorBuffer seems to allow direct memory access. But to understand how it is used and how to properly access would need to dig into. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h

Comment: Ok I will look at it. Thanks!

Comment: The tensorflow homepage also recommends to ask questions on stackoverflow about tensor. Tagged with tensorflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tensorflow so it would we worth to ask for the fastest method, if any, to assign data form a given array without copying.